# UINavigationBar appearance tint color affects system windows, bug or intended?

Tags: ios11

In iOS 10 one can set the tint color of the navigation bar for all the app using this line of code:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.green
```

However when the same is done in iOS 11, it seems to also affect system views. For example, when showing a UIActivityViewController with this code:

```
let titleText = "SOME TITLE"
let urlStr = "https://google.com"
let activityItems = [titleText,urlStr]
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)
```

And selecting the "Add to Notes" option, the navigation bar is shown with the previously set color (green in this case)

I would like to ask, is this is a bug or is it intended?

(I already filed a bug report to apple a little over a month ago but didn't get a response)

Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

Comment: Hi! I'm just experiencing the same situation. The tint color was taken from the appearance proxy as you said. There is somebody else asking in the forums. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/83931 For me the only solution was to change the tintColor before presentation and use the completion callback to rollback, hack-ish but the only way so far.

Comment: Hey, I ended doing the same thing as you but also felt kinda hackish which is why i didn't add it as an answer. But thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply Subclass `UINavigationController` and set the appearance proxy like so?

```
UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [YourUINavigationControllerSubclass.self]).barTintColor = UIColor.green
```

This a lot less hacky and it will solve the issue without any negative effects.

You can find a bit more info on the subject [here](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/customizing-the-interface/appearance-styling/#toc_uinavigationbar-and-uitoolbar-styling).

Comment: Checked the link, it seems the solution might work. I haven't tried it myself since I'd have to subclass a lot of viewcontrollers so it isn't easily implemented.

Comment: It’s only solution I found that didn’t break something else. Thanks for accepting my answer!